# Table<T>.DeleteOnSubmit generated SQL matching all columns

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I'm running into an issue on a brownfield project that is using LINQ to SQL whereby a call to `Table<T>.DeleteOnSubmit` results in a SQL query that has a `WHERE` clause for every column in the table.

Is this the default behavior and how can I change it so that it only matches on the primary key?

**Edit**

To confirm, the generated class has a primary key:

```
[Column(Name="id", Storage="_Id", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, 
        DbType="BigInt NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
public long Id
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: @pst - `dataContext.GetTable<Something>().Delete(something); dataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - the Linq-to-SQL data model has a property called `UpdateCheck` for each of your columns in any table. That property indicates whether or not that column will be used to check that a row hasn't changed before updating it.

That same property also is used to check that a row hasn't changed before deleting it. So if you just set all the column's (except the primary key) to `UpdateCheck = Never` in your model, then you should get what you're looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your SQL table structure or your LINQ-to-SQL classes, it's difficult to tell.

However, the behavior you see is to identify the record when the LINQ-to-SQL layer doesn't believe that there is a primary key on the table.

You should regenerate your LINQ-to-SQL classes against the table in question, and see if that doesn't produce the correct model with the primary key properly attributed.

Comment: There's definitely a primary key on it. Damn, I was hoping it was an obvious issue.